# Should I accept automated PRs from dependabot that update yarn.lock?

Tags: javascript, npm, dependency-management, yarnpkg, pull-request

In a JS library I work on, I've been getting some PRs from "dependabot", such as [this one](https://github.com/stevage/mapbox-gl-utils/pull/8/commits/84d3a98933a59caf1a9dc396d9481c4639ff5b47).

I get that they are trying to help by updating to later versions of dependencies. But the weird thing is each PR updates just the version of the dependency in yarn.lock - these aren't libraries that my library depends on directly.

Does this make sense to accept? I hadn't really considered the yarn.lock file as something worth managing in its own right.

Answer (score 3):

Sub-dependencies are also dependencies. If there's an exploitable vulnerability in a sub-dependency that isn't hidden or mitigated by the dependency that pulled it in, it can just as much affect your application.

Regarding the specific PR you linked, the author of the only commit in the new version [explicitly states](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/mixin-deep/commit/90ee1fab375fccfd9b926df718243339b4976d50#commitcomment-35730755) that it could cause a vulnerability and has even assigned [CVE-2019-10746](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-10746/).

Comment: Yes, but there's no guarantee that upgraded sub-dependencies are compatible with their parent packages.

Comment: Dependabot will not update dependencies which do not match the dependency version range(s) specified by your package, respectively the version range(s) specified within the dependencies which pull it in. That means the update _should_ be compatible. Of course, the PR should run through the usual test suite, because semver- and other mistakes happen.

If Dependabot found a security vulnerability / malware in a dependency, but cannot mitigate it without disrupting the dependency graph, it will simply raise a Dependabot alert w/o an associated PR.